# Gliding average or sliding average

Tags: excel, math, statistics, regression, moving-average

I need to compute the sliding or gliding average of the experimental data.

Could you guide me how to do sliding average? I could not find reference about it. I only found some information about the moving average. Is the moving average the same as the sliding average?

Thanks
Karunaras

Answer (score 2):

Yes. "moving average" and "sliding average" are the same thing. I have never heard the term "gliding average" but I don't see why it would be different.

Comment: I should detect the shift of process. Do you know what is the best selection of a moving average length?

Comment: There is no universal "best length" unfortunately, because there are so many different models. A weather forecaster may use a couple of hours, a geologist a few thousand years, and a accountant a few months. If you have a more specific question, feel free to ask it.